# How can I delete non-mp3 files recursively using fish shell?

Tags: command-line, mp3, rm, fish

The tree list is like this:

```
/Music
|--- folder1
|--- folder2
|--- folder3
|    |---- folder3.1
|    |---- folder3.2 
|    \---- folder3.3
|--- folder4
```

I had tried the command `rm | ls -R | grep -v "*.mp3"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find` command:

```
find /Music -type f ! -name '*.mp3' -delete
```